# Xiaomi Mi Unlock "Not connected to the phone"

Tags: android

I am going insane here and I need help now.

I am trying to unlock my **Xiaomi Mi Note 4**'s bootloader since almost 2 weeks, but I am stuck in this problem where the **Mi Unlock** tool can't recognize that my phone is connected.

Yes, I already have applied for and received permission from Xiaomi to unlock my device. Yes, I have waited for more than 4 days already.
The problem here is that the Mi Unlock tool simply can't see my device in bootloader mode. And it is connected, as I can see it in the Device Manager:

[image]

Mi Unlock simply can't see it:

[image]

If I click on the gear icon on the top, it says that the drivers aren't installed:

[image]

But if I click to check, it says they are installed:

[image]

Fastboot also sees the device:

[image]

What's going on here? I really need help.
I am on **Windows 10 Professional 64-bits**, all latest updates installed.

All help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Hey I had the same problem just paste the extracted folder in C drive and execute it works..